# Return a cloned object from Map in Hazelcast

Tags: spring, distributed-caching, hazelcast

I'm using Spring @Cacheable annotation with Hazelcast 2.1 and 
Spring 3.1.

```
@Cacheable("testCache")
public MyObject testMethod(int testParam);

//After method call
MyObject test = Hazelcast.getMap("testCache").get("key")
test.setSomeProp()   //This line causes an update to the cache since it is reference.
```

Is it possible to return a clone/copy of the cached value from map instead of reference from **Hazelcast.getMap()**    ?

Namely I want a copyOnRead functionality like in EhCache. See [EhCache Documentation](http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/user-guide/configuration#copyonread-and-copyonwrite-cache-configuration)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't use near cache and disable the cache-value. Ex:

```
 <hz:map name="map"
            backup-count="1"
            max-size="0"
            read-backup-data="true"
            cache-value="false"/>
```

then Hazelcast will always return you the copy of the actual value no matter what.

If you keep cache-value = true then Hazelcast will cache the object version of the value and will return you the same copy on local reads. By local read I mean the member that read is initiated and the owner of the key is same.

Comment: Thanks @Fuad. That is what I exactly needed.I've noticed that there is a part about "cache-value"  in the documentation after your answer but it is in a different chapter (Common Gotchas). It would be great to see this kind of configuration stuff in a related chapter so that they can be easier to find